# Jprofiler- how to find out application actual rendering time of pages

Tags: jvm-hotspot, jprofiler

In our application, there are scheduler queries running in background.
While profiling the code through Jprofiler in Java EE & probes - JBDC

1. thread selection - all thread groups
2. aggregation level - methods
3. thread status - all states is selected.

so the list of JDBC queries shown under Java EE & probes - JBDC contains scheduler related queries as well, and they contribute to hotspot list.

My question is : when i launch my application and start profiling code, does the time incurred in execution of scheduler queries a part of the time required to render the pages of my applicaion or that time is independent?

Also is there a option in Jprofiler to have exact time like Httpwatch that shows the time to render application pages?

Answer (score 0):

"scheduler query" does not sound like any pages are rendered.

You can see page rendering times in the URL nodes in the call tree. They show the servlet path rather than a method name.